# How can i make Postfix use new ip adresses?

Tags: postfix

I'm using Postfix in my ubuntu vps and I have 2 IPs available. I'd like that my postfix can access to my others ips, and use them randoomly.

How can I do this?

For example: main IP: 66.66.66.66 other IP: 66.66.66.67 second ip : 66.66.66.68

Comment: Please don't send spam, nor ask us how to send spam.

Comment: who told you i will send spam? you just talk without knowing the background.

Comment: Why would you want to send from multiple IPs?  I can't think of any legitimate reason for doing so.

Answer (score 2):

Configure the interface binding via: `postconf -e "inet_interfaces = all`

See [`man postconf`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/postconf)

> inet_interfaces (default: all)
>   The network interface addresses that this mail system receives mail on. Specify "all" to  receive  mail  on  all  network
>   interfaces  (default),  and  "loopback-only" to receive mail on loopback network interfaces only (Postfix version 2.2 and
>   later).  The parameter also controls delivery of mail to user@[ip.address].
>
> Note 1: you need to stop and start Postfix when this parameter changes.
>
> Note 2: address information may be enclosed inside [], but this form is not required here.
>
> When inet_interfaces specifies just one IPv4 and/or IPv6 address that is not a loopback address, the Postfix SMTP  client
>   will  use  this  address as the IP source address for outbound mail. Support for IPv6 is available in Postfix version 2.2
>   and later.
>
> On a multi-homed firewall with separate Postfix instances listening on the "inside" and "outside"  interfaces,  this  can
>   prevent  each  instance  from  being  able  to  reach  remote  SMTP  servers on the "other side" of the firewall. Setting
>   smtp_bind_address to 0.0.0.0 avoids the potential problem for IPv4, and setting smtp_bind_address6 to :: solves the prob‐
>   lem for IPv6.
>
> A better solution for multi-homed firewalls is to leave inet_interfaces at the default value and instead use explicit IP
>   addresses in the master.cf SMTP server definitions.  This preserves the Postfix SMTP client's loop detection, by ensuring
>   that each side of the firewall knows that the other IP address is still the same host. Setting $inet_interfaces to a sin‐
>   gle IPv4 and/or IPV6 address is primarily useful with virtual hosting of domains on secondary IP addresses, when each  IP
>   address serves a different domain (and has a different $myhostname setting).
>
> See also the proxy_interfaces parameter, for network addresses that are forwarded to Postfix by way of a proxy or address
>   translator.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
>  inet_interfaces = all (DEFAULT)
>  inet_interfaces = loopback-only (Postfix version 2.2 and later)
>  inet_interfaces = 127.0.0.1
>  inet_interfaces = 127.0.0.1, [::1] (Postfix version 2.2 and later)
>  inet_interfaces = 192.168.1.2, 127.0.0.1
> ```

`postconf -e` is an utility programm to maintain the postfix configuration.

> **-e**     Edit  the  main.cf configuration file, and update parameter set‐
>                tings with the "name=value" pairs  on  the  postconf(1)  command
>                line.  The  file is copied to a temporary file then renamed into
>                place.  Specify quotes to protect special characters and  white‐
>                space on the postconf(1) command line.

Any configuration changes needs to be recognized a restart of postfix.

Comment: When i use this command `postconf -e "inet_interfaces = all` nothing appair so how can i configure it with this command?

Comment: @CjayOmar see update

Answer (score -1):

This is a config blog from `/etc/postfix/main.cf` that should work for all interfaces on a machine.

```
myhostname = my_machine_name
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = my_machine_name, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
```

If you are in Ubuntu you can run the following to reconfigure Postfix via a wizard:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix
```

Why would these solutions not work for you?

EDIT: Run `ifconfig` on your machine and check the `inet addr` connected to each interface on that machine. If you do not see `66.66.66.66` or `66.66.66.67` there, then your machine cannot see either address so the postfix config is meaningless.

Comment: Only one line from that config should be in this answer.  The rest of them are unnecessary noise.

Comment: do you mean this one ̉`inet_interfaces = 127.0.0.1, 66.66.66.66, 66.66.66.67` do esnt work it says when i restart postfix this error : postfix: fatal: parameter inet_interfaces: no local interface found for 66.66.66.67

Comment: Check my edit to the answer. If it is set to `all` then any IP connected to that machine would be valid. So you should be able to just use it out of the box. If you are specifying an address and it fails with `no interface` then that IP doesn’t even exist as far as the machine is concerned or postfix is concerned.

Comment: You are right bro i have added interfaces and my ips appair, so how can i make postfix rotate them ?

Comment: Bro? Good luck, dude.

Comment: Do u have any idea Jake ??